# How can i remove or change text from a matplotlib plot?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a bar plot which is being returned to me (i have access to the AxesSubplot object) which already has some labels on the bars. The issue is they are illegible and i would like to enlarge them (or clear and reset them). Take the following code for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['red','green','blue'], 'b':[4,8,12]})
plot = df.plot(kind='barh')

for i in plot.patches:
    plot.text(i.get_width()+.01, i.get_y()+.38, str(i.get_width()), fontsize=31)
```

This generates a nice bar plot with labels on the bars. But lets say i want to remove or change those labels, how can this be done?

Comment: I don't understand, if you want to remove them, why don't you just omit the `for i in plot.patches...`, or to change the size, change the `fontsize` argument?

Comment: As i said in the question the plot is being returned to me (from a function call) so its already built into the object. The code is just a dummy example

Comment: Oh OK, I think I get it, see my answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the text objects using `plot.texts`. In your example, you get:

```
>>> plot.texts
[Text(4.01,0.13,'4'), Text(8.01,1.13,'8'), Text(12.01,2.13,'12')]
```

You can remove them all in a loop:

```
for t in plot.texts:
    t.set_visible(False)
```

Or change attributes (fontsize for example) in a similar manner:

```
for t in plot.texts:
    # Reduce fontsize to 10:
    t.set_fontsize(10)
```